# Why does shrinking the transaction log generate lots of log (LOP_SHRINK_NOOP) and not shrink the log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, shrink

I just tried shrinking an overly big log file (FULL recovery model). This operation is not expected to always succeed and indeed the log was not shrunk.

But I observed that a lot of new log was generated. At a log file size of about 20GB each shrink attempt generated a few hundred MB of new log. I repeated the shrink operation a few times and received the same result each time.

Reading out the log I found that all of that space was for `LOP_SHRINK_NOOP` log records. The web does not have information about this log record type.

`DBCC LOGINFO` shows that there is a mix of active and unused VLFs. There is one used VLF at the end of the file ( `Status = 2`).

Why does attempting to shink the log sometimes...

1. ...cause lots of new log data?
2. ...not shrink the log file although apparently work was performed on it?
3. ...generate LOP_SHRINK_NOOP records? What does that log record type mean and when is it expected to appear?

The statement used was:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('logfilename', 8192) --shrink to 8GB
```

Log file size on disk: 20GB

Log allocated size as reported by DMV: ~2GB

The log was not backed up prior to performing the `SHRINKFILE`. After performing a log backup the shrink succeeded.

Comment: What command did you use? Did you give it a reasonable smaller size or did you just say 1 MB as in `SHRINKFILE(file, 1)`? What size was it? Did you back the log up first? Did you back the log up twice to ensure it wrapped around? Is it possible that there were a lot of attempts to shuffle data around that failed because of open transactions etc.?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I appended more information. I do not think I backed up the log twice (did not know about that technique). All transactions running at that point in time probably have been short-lived.

Comment: I am commenting because I can't tell you exactly what is in the LOP_SHRINK_NOOP records, but I can draw relatively educated guesses based on your update. The shrink failed to do anything because the log hadn't been backed up; these records represent data that was potentially assembled to be moved or removed but then couldn't. I bet they disappear when the log can be successfully shrunk?

Comment: Robert Davis taught me about the double-tap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628/how-do-you-clear-the-sql-server-transaction-log/18292136#comment26837713_18292136

Comment: @AaronBertrand good to know. I always insert a few MB into a throwaway table to roll the log over... very primitive. My guess is that LOP_SHRINK_NOOP is dummy data used to roll the log over. A hack in other words. What do you mean by "they disappear"? Yes, now that the log is shrunk the shrink log records are gone.

Comment: I mean that when you're trying to shrink the log, they are stuck there because the log hasn't been backed up, so true reorganization is not possible. Once the log has been backed up, they can be moved correctly or simply jettisoned.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was not aware that log contents are ever moved. I do think that those dummy records were backed up, the VLFs marked as unused and then truncated off when I shrank the file. I do not think any part of the engine knows what those records mean besides the shrink code (and the restore code that ignores them).

Comment: Like I said, I don't know for sure. Just grasping and guessing at potential explanations for the behavior. Unless the data was being shuffled around for movement, I don't know why these NOOP records would be created if the whole point of them is to just delete them on shrink.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Similar question here http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/140553/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith No, never found out. My current guess: The NOOP records are *meant* to roll the log over but there is a bug in this rarely executed code path so it does not actually roll it over.

Comment: In case somebody is not aware: "NOOP" means "no-op" which means "no operation". This is a programmer term that means "This operation does nothing but it has to happen because of some implementation choice".